# Is there any way to create an object of same model or class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

I would like to add a manager Id in my Employee class or model in ASP net Core my code below:

```
namespace WorkPermit.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Employee Number")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee Number")]
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Employee Name")]
        [Display(Name ="Employee Name")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Employee Phone Number")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee Phone Number")]
        public int EmployeePhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("JobTitle")]
        [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select The Job Title")]
        public int JobID { get; set; }
        public virtual JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }


    }
}



namespace WorkPermit.Models
{
    public class JobTitle
    {
        [Key]
        public int JobID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Job Title")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string JobName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the end I want to create object of the same class employee is manager and manager manage list of employees.

Comment: A better structure would be to have an `IEmployee` interface, and have a manager class which conforms to this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this where the manager is also an employee. An employee can have many employees, in that case, he's the manager or whatever you call it to those children employees. So, if `ManagerID` is null, it means the employee doesn't have a manager.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set;} 
    public int? ManagerID {get;set;}  
    public Employee Manager{get;set;} 
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but ('public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees') not worked in migration please help @Qudus

Comment: there is no error but it doesn't work in migration @Qudus

Comment: i will put it in your answer post @Qudus

Comment: @AliHabib how do you know it doesn't work?